# Joomla : Can a super administrator get the ftp password of that site (from configuration file or any other way)?

Tags: php, joomla, security, joomla1.5

I have access to a joomla 1.5 made site's backend as super administrator. Now what i want to do is, take that site down and set a simple html file as the site homepage. To do that i think i need ftp user/pass. Is there any way to get that pass from joomla backend? I can see some entries in Help>System info>Configuration file  where $ftp_user:'xxxxxx' and $ftp_pass: 'xxxxxx'. Is there any way to know these values?
Even if i can't get the ftp user/pass, can i edit/browse any file/directory using joomla backend in some way?

Comment: do u want only to put a static html page on site?

Comment: if possible, i want to browse files & edit too. Only putting a static page would not fully satisfy my purpose.

Comment: yes you can make changes in template after installation.see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the FTP user/password is saved in the Joomla configuration.php file. At backend, go to the Global Configuration and view the HTML-source, search for *jform_smtppass* and find the password value next to it.

Only tested with Joomla! 2.5.6.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i was asking for!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have need of ftp details you can do this by using your simple super-admin control.Do this:-
1.create a new theme having just a simple HTML page and required css,images.
2.add this theme to joomla.
3.make this theme as your default theme,now you can see the html page that you recently integrated in your new theme.

Comment: Thanks. But i need ftp pass or some other way to do that. The main point is i don't want the joomla site to reside there, i want to backup that site, then delete all of it, and then put a static html as site index file. All i have now is super-admin access.

Comment: than you should have ftp controller to take a back up and do all other things.!!